# Python Discord bot error I haven’t seen before

Tags: python, discord, replit

I started this code a bit ago in repl.it but each time I try to run it, it throws me this weird error. Could someone help me figure this out?

I’m trying to make a !purge command for a Discord bot, but whenever i try to add in an Embedded message that would pop up in a command-logs channel, it stops and doesn’t execute any more code in that function after the bugged line(s). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here’s the bugged code:

```
@client.command()

@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Server Owner")

async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
  
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1) #to delete the command

  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount) #to delete the messages
  
  channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="command-logs")

  emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="Purge command used", description=f"{user.name}#{user.discriminator} used !purge to delete {amount} messages.")

  await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: What weird error?

Answer (score 1):

You have three main errors in your code and you can also "improve" it a bit.

**Firstly:**

To delete the authors message you can simply use `await ctx.message.delete()` but your method works fine too.

**Secondly:**

You want `user.name` to be displayed but never defined it. To overcome this error you can use:

```py
    user= ctx.author # Author is the new user
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="Purge command used",
                        description=f"{user.name}#{user.discriminator} used !purge to delete {amount} messages.")
```

**Thirdly:**

If you want to send the message into a certain channel you have to get the author of the command, do this with `ctx.author` as `member` was never defined.

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="command-logs")
```

**Full code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Server Owner")
async def purging(ctx, amount: int):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="command-logs")
    user = ctx.author

    if channel:
        await ctx.message.delete()

        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)  # to delete the messages

        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="command-logs")
        user = ctx.author
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="Purge command used",
                            description=f"{user} used !purge to delete {amount} messages.")

        await channel.send(embed=emb)
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="Purge command used",
                            description=f"{user} used !purge to delete {amount} messages.")

        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

- The `if/else` statement is used because if the channel does not exist an error in the console occurs. If the channel does not exist, the message is sent to the channel in which the command was executed.

Comment: @AnsonRau Glad I was able to help. If this was the best answer/helped you the most don't forget to "accept" the answer, so users with the same problem can see the most helpful answer right away.